# Sort array by nested key while keeping existing sort the same

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of doctors, each with multiple key-value pairs

```
doctor {
  type: "bla",
  doctor-name: "bla",
  doctor-state-id: "bla",
  doctor-state: "AL",
  ...
}
```

I am running a for loop to display the list on the front-end. The way they are displayed is by state, imagine an `<li>` tag with the state as the header, and then the doctors listed below. The next state has another `<li>` and so on. Currently, only the states are listed alphabetically, but the doctor's names within aren't.

I guess that I cannot sort the array within the for loop, and I have tried several other `ksort`, `usort` and `asort` methods with the intention to keep the indexes the same. Any clues?

here is a more discrete example:

```
Alaska
John Doe, MD, PhD - Anchorage - Neurosurgeon
Jane Doe, MD, MBI - Anchorage - Neurosurgeon
```

Jane Doe needs to come before John Doe.

Comment: What have you tried?   Please refer to our [ask] page and come back to edit the question with the necessary adjustments

Comment: You may be looking for `uasort`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use `uasort()` and in the comparison function return the state's sort order, but if it's the same state, return the sort order of the name of the person.

```php
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a['doctor-state'] == $b['doctor-state']) {
    return strcmp($a['doctor-name'], $b['doctor-name']);
  } else {
    return strcmp($a['doctor-state'], $b['doctor-state']);
  }
});
```

Comment: This actually works, except that in the first state it took both entries and made it the same. E.G. I had John Doe and Jane Doe and now they are both John Doe. The other states seem fine and correct

Comment: @Hendrik That would likely be an issue of uasort vs usort. I've updated the answer to use uasort.

Comment: uasort breaks the sorting, and leaves the list of names unsorted